# using linq, how can i create a IEnumerable<> from a property of another IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people
```

and i want to get this:

```
IEnumerable<Dog> peoplesDogs
```

where **Dogs** is a property of a **person** object and also a

```
 IEnumerable<Dog>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var peoplesDogs = people.SelectMany(p => p.Dogs);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var peoplesDogs = from p in people 
                  from d in p.Dogs
                  select d;
```

Comment: @John: Fair enough... must have been quick :)

Comment: can i have my two points back? unless this one is also broken, i was guessing

Comment: @John: Yes, I undid the downvote. Still, the fact that the property was "Dogs" should have been a hint from the start ;)

Comment: @Skeet Might want to remove the original comment, lot of people wont read past that ;)

Comment: But now the comments make no sense!  You're "bickering" over a point that is no longer visible!

Answer (score 0):

```
var peopleDogs = people.Select(p => p.Dogs)
```

**Edit**

The above would create an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Dog>>` but apparently what is needed is just `IEnumerable<Dog>`.

As in LukeH's answer, you need to use `SelectMany` to flatten:

```
var peopleDogs = people.SelectMany(p => p.Dogs)
```

Comment: -1 for the same reason as John Sheehan's answer was originally wrong. This needs to be flattened, typically with SelectMany as per LukeH's answer and John Sheehan's answer. I understand this is due to a question edit, but it's still wrong for the current question - I'd suggest deleting it.

Comment: the original question didn't state that it was also IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
var peoplesDogs = from p in people
                  from d in p.Dogs
                  select d;
```

which has the same effect as:

```
var peoplesDogs = people.SelectMany(p => p.Dogs)
```